# upgrade from windows phone 8 to UWP

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have windows phone 8 app available since two years in windows phone store. However, I would like to migrate my app to UWP, but I have below concerns;

1. Is it possible to migrate from windows phone 8 to UWP? (not windows phone 8.x then to UWP)
2. Is Windows phone 8 apps will be available in Windows 10 store?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the Windows 10 Dev-Guide-Videos, you need to do the following steps to migrate a WP8 app to windows 10

1. Port the UI Silverlight -> Windows XAML
2. Rewrite code to target UAP APIs
3. Design UX for multiple form factors

Watch this video for details - https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10-Preview/03